# Comprehensive list of combination techniques for word-level embeddings with pros/cons

Tags: references, natural-language, word-embeddings

Are there any reference document(s) that give a comprehensive list combination techniques for [word-level embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) along with their pros/cons (and ideally some pointers to publications where they were successful or not so successful)?

---

Example of combination techniques for word-level embeddings: sum.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The team around Bengio published an article a few years ago. Maybe this is good enough?

> Turian, J., Ratinov, L., & Bengio, Y. (2010). [Word representations: a simple and general method for semi-supervised learning](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1858721) (pp. 384–394). Association for Computational Linguistics.