# Word embeddings with logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, word-embeddings

My goals is to classify a set of documents (e.g. [20newsgroups](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html)) into one of twenty categories. I can do this using [Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) for example which takes as input a sparse $D\times V$ matrix in which each row is a document and each column represents a tf-idf smoothed count of words in that document.

Instead of using the sparse tf-idf matrix, I want to classify based on word-embeddings ([word2vec](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf) or [Glove](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf)) where each word is represented by e.g. a 300 dimensional vector. My question is how do you represent a document of word vectors as an input to a logistic regression that takes as input a matrix of size n_samples by n_features? How do you classify a document based on word embeddings?

Comment: I think the term-of-art you're looking for is doc2vec.

Answer (score 6):

While it's possible to combine word embeddings using weighted average or a concatenation of min / max values across word vectors as described in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221715/apply-word-embeddings-to-entire-document-to-get-a-feature-vector/), the output vector loses semantic information. A better alternative is to train a [doc2vec](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4053v2.pdf) model which is an extension of word2vec that uses paragraph vectors as part of the context during training:

[image: doc2vec]

The word vectors in doc2vec are shared across all paragraphs while the paragraph vectors are unique to each paragraph. The doc2vec model is implemented in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html). See the following [ipython notebook](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb) for an example and this [quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-does-doc2vec-represent-feature-vector-of-a-document-Can-anyone-explain-mathematically-how-the-process-is-done) for additional explanation of the doc2vec model.