# Why do convolutional neural networks benefit from input translation?

Tags: neural-networks

Following this [tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html), it shows that a CNN accuracy on MNIST is improved even when the training set is expanded with simple operations such as one pixel translation. The same tutorial then asks

> The idea of convolutional layers is to behave in an invariant way across images. It may seem surprising, then, that a network can learn more when all we've done is translate the input data. Can you explain why this is actually quite reasonable?

I was thinking because the pool layer (max or L2) somehow is a sort approximation and loose the precise spatial information. [This answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3kjlio/question_on_a_problem_from_michael_nielsons/) instead says it is due to the fully connected layers:

> But the fully-connected layer (if there is one, or the output layer if not) still sees as its input a spatial map, which is probably, depending on the network architecture, mostly invariant to small shifts but less so to larger ones.

Does anyone have a better suggestion why this happens?

Comment: Does this help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350220/utility-of-feature-engineering-why-create-new-features-based-on-existing-featu/350238#350238 ?

Comment: @Tim No, not really. My question is specific to convolutional neural networks which are purposely built to be invariant. Those question and answers don't relate to CNN.